# using a variable name as the output of cat

Tags: bash

I'm having some strange behavior from bash here. I have several files, some of which are in multiple parts. Each file called **_Rx_00y.fastq.gz* should be concatenated with *x* as an identifier, that is R1_001 and R1_002 (as well as a hypothetical R1_003) go together.

```
    [mark@theNosebook Sample_P4]$ ls -lh
    total 822M
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 404M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R1_002.fastq.gz
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 414M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R2_002.fastq.gz
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark  144 Aug 13 12:25 SampleSheet.csv
```

I wish to take both *_R1_00x.fastq.gz files and concatenate them to the first. I realize I could use `>>` here, but it seems unwieldly if I have more than 2 entries. My solution, which I think *should* work is:

```
    name=$(ls *_R1_001.fastq.gz)
    cat $(ls *_R1_*) > ${name}
```

however, here I get

```
[mark@theNosebook Sample_P4]$ ls -lh
total 421M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:37 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R1_002.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 414M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R2_002.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark  144 Aug 13 12:25 SampleSheet.csv
```

Note that the size of the resultant output is that of only the second file (2.6M). Writing them to a separate file, here *cat*, works fine.

```
[mark@theNosebook Sample_P4]$ cat $(ls *_R1_*) > cat
[mark@theNosebook Sample_P4]$ ls -lh
total 1.2G
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark mark 407M Aug 13 12:36 cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 404M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R1_002.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 414M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark 2.6M Aug 13 12:25 P4_CTCTCTAC-AGAGTAGA_L002_R2_002.fastq.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mark mark  144 Aug 13 12:25 SampleSheet.csv
```

What's going on here? I would like to preserve the file names, as they reference the samples from which they were taken.

Thanks

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: [Don't truncate the files you're trying to read](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file). Your code says "truncate etc_001.fastq.gz and append (the now truncated) etc_001.fastq.gz to it"

Comment: using `ls` while break when: 1. your filename contains white characters, 2. your filename contains bazaar characters that will be replaced into `?`, etc. too many to enumerate. glob is much safer and accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ls`; whatever pattern you use with `ls` can just as well be used to populate an array, whose contents can then be used as the argument to `cat`. Write everything to a temp file first, to ensure the concatenation succeeds before overwriting the first file.

```
to_cat=( *_R1_* )
tmp=$(mktemp)
cat "${to_cat[@]}" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "${to_cat[0]}"
```

You can optionally ensure that you found files to concatenate. (I'd recommend it, just to be safe.)

```
shopt -s nullglob
to_cat=( *_R1_*)
tmp=$(mktemp)
(( ${#to_cat[@]} )) && cat "${to_cat[@]}" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "${to_cat[0]}"
```

Comment: This works. Can you explaing a couple things to me?
1. The difference between the two, i.e. what the bit before `&& cat` in the last line does
2. Why `$tmp` doesn't get curly braces but `${to_cat[n]}` does
This is the first I've worked with arrays in bash. Thanks for the eye-opener!

Comment: In the first, if `*_R1_*` doesn't match any files, the array will contain one item, the literal string `*_R1_*`, which being a file name that doesn't exist, will case an error with `cat`. In the second, the `nullglob` will cause the array to be empty instead. The `(( ... ))` is an arithmetic command that succeeds if the length of the array is non-zero, meaning the following `cat` will only execute if there is at least one matching file.

Comment: Very good. Thanks. It appears that creating the temporary file first is what makes the difference.

Comment: @mnosefish, to answer your question about curly braces, you can always refer to a basic variable like `$tmp` without the braces, though `${tmp}` will also work.  But once you start referring to arrays or if you use Parameter Expansion (as in my answer), you need braces to tell the shell the scope of your variable expression. For example, `$tmp:-foo` is very different from `${tmp:-foo}`, and `$foo_bar` is a different variable from `${foo}_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to preserve filenames, I gather that *everything* in the filename up to the last underscore is candidate for preservation, with those last three digits being an incrementing chunk identifier.

As such, you might want to process large quantities of these files, and not have to modify your script for each one.

How about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Detect a "-f" option, which forces recreation of files.
if [ "$1" = "-f" ]; then
  force=true
else
  force=false
fi

# First, get our list of prefixes into an array,
# stripping from the last underscore to the end of each name.
a=(*.fastq.gz)
prefixes="${a[@]%_*}"

# Next, step through the prefixes array, concatenating the chunks.
for prefix in "${prefixes[@]}"; do
  if [ ! -s "${prefix}_joined.fastq.gz" ] || $force; then
    cat "${prefix}"_[0-9]*.fastq.gz > "${prefix}_joined.fastq.gz"
  fi
done
```

Note the "-f" option.  I've included it so that if you *are* running this on a large collection of files, the script will quickly skip files that have been processed during a previous batch.

I recommend joining your files in *separate* files rather than overwriting your first file, so that if something goes wrong, you haven't corrupted your original data.  Results should be reproducible, after all!  :-)

Comment: The directory I've shown in my example is one of 96 or so: one for each sample. I simply did this with a for loop. 

I agree with you on that (re: reproducibility), however since all the directories I got back from the sequencer are write-protected anyway, the first line in the script is to `rsync -r --chmod a+wrx` the whole directory to a copy of the working dir, so given the initial dataset and the script, anyone would be able to reproduce the results, and I'm not terribly worried about corrupting the copy. 

That said, I do think this solution is more elegant than my own.

Comment: You can strip suffixes from each element of an array at once: `prefixes=(*.fastq.gz); prefixes=${prefixes[@]%_*}`.

Comment: Ooh!  Thanks, @chepner!

Answer (score -1):

You have to `gunzip` first

Try:

```
gunzip -c *_R1_001.fastq.gz | gzip > result.gz
```

Comment: My application doesn't require it. See this discussion: https://www.biostars.org/p/81924/
besides, it works fine without using the variable name.

Comment: In fact, you can concatenate multiple gzips together, and the result will be one larger gzip. Craziness!  All you lose is the ratio data you'd get from `gunzip -l`.